# Failed adding service reference(s). Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

This problem appears when I want add WCF web service to my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project. I use Visual Studio 2022.

The problem is as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check on similar issues there. I think your issue related to VS too

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/16110-update-service-reference-missing/1500425

Comment: here also
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/609531/adding-connected-wcf-service-to-net-3-1-project-re

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1022812/vs2022-service-reference-error-msbuild-svcutilboot